# Angular material table horizontal scroll

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to make angular material table scroll horizontally, I was able to do that with the scss:

```
.table-div {
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
  
  mat-table {
     table-layout: fixed;
       mat-header-cell, mat-cell {
         overflow-wrap: normal;
         white-space: nowrap;
         overflow: visible !important;
         margin-right: 30px;
         flex: 0 0 300px;
       }
  }
}
```

The scroll and data worked and visible. However, the overflowed rows have no color, no border, etc..
Like the table is cut at the original width border.
How can we fix that?
This image shows the border of the table and how the overflowed rows have no styling when scrolled
[image: image of problem]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
showing the problem. You could use
[Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)
to create one.

Comment: Have you tried to set the rows to ´width: fit-content !important;´

Comment: I added image showing exactly the problem

Comment: The table shows the border of the table and the overflowed data on the right

Comment: fit content didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://ampersandtutorials.com/angular/scrollable-table-in-angular-material/

Here is an [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-npvxgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss) of your issue, I have added the css needed to make the table scroll and keep the hidden elements styled

```
.table-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

mat-table {
 width: 1200px;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 display: table;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin: 0px;
}

mat-row,
mat-header-row {
  display: table-row;
}
mat-cell,
mat-header-cell {
  word-wrap: initial;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  line-break: unset;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I wrapped the material table with a div

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <mat-table>
    ...
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Comment: This requires setting a specific width to the table. In material v14 and lower horizontal scroll was achievable without setting a width on the table.